# OAuth 1.0 - how to pass token in headers?

Tags: python, oauth

There's a website require OAuth 1.0 and is requiring using a token. I tried the code:

```
def request(path=None):
    token = access_token()
    headers = { 'Authorization' : 'oauth_token %s' %  token }
    res = requests.get('https://somewebsite.com/v1'+path, headers=headers)
    print res.text
```

or replace `oauth_token` with, `access_token` or `TOK:`. They just didn't work, which returns error `Access_token is empty`. Is authentication method all different with various sites?

Comment: Why do this all yourself? Use something like [Requests-OauthLib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib) to handle this for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought this is simple, and I'm tired with endlessly searching for packages. I rarely use the whole packages. And the last I want to learn something.

Comment: @MartijnPieters anyway, let me check this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct header format is:

```
Authorization: OAuth param1_name="param1 value", param2_name="param2 value"
```

so `OAuth` followed by comma-separated name-value pairs.

The `oauth_token` key is a parameter name:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_token="%s"' %  token}
```

However, you need to send more than just the token, according to [*Accessing Protected Resources*](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor13) more parameters are expected.

If you are going to try and implement this yourself, at least take a look at the [OAuth RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) and the [Python `oauthlib` library source code](https://github.com/idan/oauthlib). There is also a [Requests-OAuthlib integration layer](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/) you can take a look at.